# How much assembly is required when an LBS orders a bike?

Tags: bottom-bracket, chainring, crankset, lbs, new-bicycle-assembly

I'm looking to order a [Marin Lombard Elite](http://www.marinbikes.com/ca/bikes/description/2015-lombard-elite) from my LBS but I want to replace the FSA BB and crankset with Shimano or SRAM parts, and change to a 52/36.

When my LBS orders it, does all of that come assembled from the manufacturer usually?  If the former, I'll just take it home and swap everything out myself, but if the latter, then I could bring them the parts when I place the order and they could just swap them in when they build it.

Comment: A good LBS will certainly be adjusting things to make sure everything is "just so", but out of the factory, a bike will come with bb and cranks all set up. So expect to pay both for new parts, and time taken to install them. Just an observation, but I do find it quite surprising when someone buys a brand new bike and then starts swapping parts immediately. Can you not find a "factory" bike more suitable for your needs?

Comment: Why do you want to dump a brand new installed FSA Gossamer?

Comment: @Blam I've read bad things about FSA.

Comment: Does it really matter to you how much work it takes them? Like always - talk to them - tell them what you want (novel idea I know, but give it a try) and ask them for two prices - you do it or they they do it. Check how it affects warranty and post sales services (if any).

Comment: @NaOH - so run the FSA until it goes. Which will be a decently long time, probably. You'll need a new BB and crankset and labor, which you can probably find a bike without the FSA stuff for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is determined by your LBS, the relationship you have with them and the bike your buying.

Generally bikes come in flat pack boxes and, with the exception of top end bikes, are partially assembled out of the factory. The reseller needs to attach the handle bar and do a safety check. If you want to change parts out you'll have to pay workshop rates.

However if you a buying a good bike from a good LBS you'll find they'll disassemble the bike, chase and face the head tube, bottom bracket and disc tabs as part of the sale. They'll also make any upgrades that you've asked for, either purchased from them or from a different reseller.

If you're purchasing the parts from them on a new bike you should expect a discounted workshop rate. If your bring the parts you shop be expecting to pay premium workshop rates.

There's no set rule of thumb. However as always ensure you have a good relationship with your LBS and they'll look after you and your bike.

Comment: Yep, it varies a bit by maker and country. Most top Italian bikes I've assembled have needed both wheels, handle bars and pedals attaching, brakes and gears adjusting, bar tape. Lower levels bikes usually need less work.

Comment: I've found the opposite.  Very cheap components (especially disc brakes) can be a pain to adjust.  I have found high end components generally adjust much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Most bikes come flat shipped from the manufacturer.  A good bike shop will do the following:
Check/adjust the wheels/hubs and then install them.
Install and lubricate/paste the seatpost.
Install the handlebars.
Check/Adjust the headset.
Check and adjust the drivetrain.
Install pedals (if the bike came with them, many high end bikes do not).
Install the reflectors (required by law in most areas).
Tune/check air levels (tires and suspension).

To answer your question specifically, the crankset/bottom bracket will most likely come pre assembled.  However, talk to your shop.  They may be willing to give you some credit for the FSA crankset if they keep it and they can assure it is unridden (but not uninstalled).  I have worked in a shop that did so regularly with the stock SPD pedals that come on bikes if people wanted flats.

Comment: I worked at a bike shop 20 to 25 years ago and that sounds about right.  In addition we would adjust the headset and hub bearings.  This was in the days of quill stems, but I don't think much would really change, other than the need to cut down steerer tubes to suit the rider, presumably.